# Canvas draw behind div issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using a javascript to draw inside a canvas, but I'm getting this weird issue where I cant "draw behind" the div of text, so when I hover over the div, it stops drawing and starts whenever i hover off the div and the line starts to continue where I hover off, but it renders weird line behind the div instead of line with styling like blur.

At this point, I'd like to solve this problem in the way that i can draw behind the text.

Here is my code: `(https://codepen.io/Zdendaaa/pen/yXWOmQ)`

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please post your relevant code in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've pasted wrong link. This edited link is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `pointer-events: none` as described in the other answer, but this is only a good solution, if you're sure that you don't need any other events on that specific element. For example if you want to place an image inside your content div which should have an hover effect or let's say any kind of link, you're stuck with the same problem again.

A better approach would probably be to just wrap the canvas and your content in another div container and just add your `mouseover` listener to this wrapping element instead.

In this case you don't have to prohibit certain events on specific elements.

I edited your pen a bit with an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQbGKL

Comment: That is actually a problem I would have, because I wanted to paste a link with hover effect here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To your content div add

`pointer-events: none;`

According to MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events
The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea what might cause the problem, when mouse is moving very fast so the "blur" effect is not shown and there is only straight line without that blur effect?

Comment: I think you're exiting the div and then the mouse is re-entering the area.